# ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration method doesn't return value for keys

Tags: c#, wpf, config, configuration-files

I am using the **ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration** method trying to get to keys from appSettings dynamicaly.I have the file updated dynamicaly so After the updated I am trying to open it and get the new values for the new keys.

Example:
In the beggining my file looks like:

```
<appSettings>
 <add key = "CZH" value = "Chezch Republic"/>
 <add key = "DEN" value = "Denmark"/>
</appSettings>
```

and at some point I am adding a new key/value pair to this section and it looks like that:

```
 <appSettings>
     <add key = "CZH" value = "Chezch Republic"/>
     <add key = "DEN" value = "Denmark"/>
     <add key = "ITA" value = "Italy"/>
    </appSettings>
```

So, after the adding I want to get the new value and its key, BUT I can not see a way tha to happen.All that I could get is the **AllKeys** where everything is okay, but I want to have also the value for the new key added.

I have my file open in Notepad++ and I can see that it is properly updated but I don't know how to get the value for the new key.

EDIT:OK, I'll try to explain it once more and this time I really hope that somenone is going to understand me.

With the  **ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(path_to_the_file)** I am loading the configuration file of my application. The return type of  the method is : **configuration**
One of its properties is **AllKeys** and when I call it, it returns exactly what I need - All the updated keys, **BUT**  I don't know how to get the values for those keys.I am wondering if there is a method or property of the **configuration object** that the **ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(path_to_the_file)** method returns.

This is all that I am asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this after adding new value to app.config

```
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection(“appSettings”);
```

See the article for more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.refreshsection.aspx

```
AppSettingsSection appSettings = (AppSettingsSection)config.GetSection("appSettings");
string ITAValue =  appSettings.Settings[“ITA”].Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Private Sub readsettings()
    Dim mySettings As NameValueCollection = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("ConnectionStrings")
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    While i < mySettings.Count
        Console.WriteLine("#{0} Key: {1} Value: {2}", i, mySettings.GetKey(i), mySettings(i))
        System.Math.Max(System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(i), i - 1)
    End While
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None).FilePath
```

See if you are loading the currect file. else wise. use custom file location.

```
 ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration("myfilepath.exe");
```

if you are adding removing or changing appsettings on the fly. then i suggest you to use the [File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.appsettingssection.file.aspx) attribute on [appSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.appsettingssection.aspx) Sections.

Comment: I have the file loaded properly.I am not looking for a way to load the correct file.

I am just looking for a way to get the values for the keys in the appSettings section.

Comment: you need to refresh the section of appSettings. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.refreshsection(v=vs.80).aspx